# How to close a screen from a Makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-screen

I have a test that depend on a specific HTTP server, which requires me to start one with a known setup for the tests.

Since the server cannot be started as a daemon my approach was to just have it start in a `screen` session, run the test and close the session.

```
test:
    screen -S test_http_server -d -m start_my_test_http_server                 
    # run my tests here                             
    screen -S test_http_server -X kill # works from bash but not makefile :/
```

Everything works fine except for closing or killing the session (which does work if I run it in `bash` afterwards).

Comment: I can't think of any reason that would fail. What happens if you put the two screen commands and the intervening tests in a shell script, and simply execute that script from the Makefile instead?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that using the `@` prefix (which I did, but was not posted in the original example code) that suppresses the normal 'echo' of the command somehow interferes with closing the screen.

Fails because of @ prefix usage.

```
test:
    @screen -S test_http_server -d -m start_my_test_http_server                 
    # run my tests here                             
    @screen -S test_http_server -X kill
```

Fixed make file that works as intended.

```
test:
    screen -S test_http_server -d -m start_my_test_http_server                 
    # run my tests here                             
    screen -S test_http_server -X kill
```